# how to show balance by subtract sum Expense list items from sum Income List items in Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm building expense tracker app using flutter, I got idea how to show income and expense from firebase firestore database but I don't know how to show balance by subtracting sum of all items in expense list from sum of all items in income list.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:daily_expense/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../size_config.dart';

class TopBalanceCard extends StatelessWidget {
 TopBalanceCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;




    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Container(
        height: getProportionateScreenHeight(200),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text(
                'B A L A N C E',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: kSecondaryColor,
                    fontSize: getProportionateScreenHeight(18)),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: _firebaseFirestore
                      .collection('new transactions')
                      .where("UID",
                          isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    var finalBalance = 0;
                    final tran = snapshot.data?.docs;
                    if (tran == null) {
                      print("balance is null");
                    } else {
                      //this is where I stuck, I want to show the balance 
                      /*I don't know how to show balance by subtracting sum of all items in expense list from sum of all items in income list.
I'm building expense tracker app using flutter, I got idea how to show income and expense from firebase firestore database but I don't know how to show balance by subtracting sum of all items in expense list from sum of all items in income list.*/
                    }
                    return Text(
                      //show balance
                      '$finalBalance',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: kTextColor,
                          fontSize: getProportionateScreenHeight(35)),
                    );
                  }),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey[200]),
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_upward_rounded,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                stream: null,
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  return Text(
                                    'Income',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: kTextColor,
                                        fontSize:
                                            getProportionateScreenHeight(18)),
                                  );
                                }),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                stream: _firebaseFirestore
                                    .collection('new transactions')
                                    .where("UID",
                                        isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth
                                            .instance.currentUser!.email)
                                    .where("incomeOrExpense",
                                        isEqualTo: "income")
                                    .snapshots(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  var finalIncome = 0;
                                  List<String> totalIncome = [];
                                  final tran = snapshot.data?.docs;
                                  if (tran == null) {
                                    print("income is null");
                                  } else {
                                    for (var i in tran) {
                                      String income = i.get('amount');
                                      totalIncome.add(income);
                                    }
                                    List<int> lint = totalIncome
                                        .map((e) => int.parse(e))
                                        .toList();
                                    lint.forEach((element) {
                                      finalIncome += element;
                                    });
                                  }
                                  return Text(
                                     /*here I'm showing income from the list accessed from database.   I'm building expense tracker app using flutter, I got idea how to show income and expense from firebase firestore database but I don't know how to show balance by subtracting sum of all items in expense list from sum of all items in income list. this is just because stackoverflow showed error to add more details to my code*/
                                    '₹ $finalIncome',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize:
                                            getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
                                  );
                                })
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.grey[200]),
                            child: const Center(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_downward_rounded,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Expense',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: kTextColor,
                                    fontSize: getProportionateScreenHeight(18)),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5),
                              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                  stream: _firebaseFirestore
                                      .collection('new transactions')
                                      .where("UID",
                                          isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth
                                              .instance.currentUser!.email)
                                      .where('incomeOrExpense',
                                          isEqualTo: 'Expense')
                                      .snapshots(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    var finalExpense = 0;
                                    List<String> totalExpense = [];
                                    final tran = snapshot.data?.docs;
                                    if (tran == null) {
                                      print("expense is null");
                                    } else {
                                      for (var i in tran) {
                                        String expense = i.get('amount');
                                        totalExpense.add(expense);
                                      }
                                      List<int> intEx = totalExpense
                                          .map((e) => int.parse(e))
                                          .toList();
                                      intEx.forEach((element) {
                                        finalExpense += element;
                                      });
                                    }
                                    return Text(
                                      /* here I'm showing expense from the list accessed from database.  I'm building expense tracker app using flutter, I got idea how to show income and expense from firebase firestore database but I don't know how to show balance by subtracting sum of all items in expense list from sum of all items in income list.*/
                                      '₹ $finalExpense',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize:
                                              getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
                                    );
                                  })
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
         ),
         ),
        );
        }
      }
```

Comment: could you include the firestore response?

Comment: You can use a loop to go through all documents and calculate the balance - but this will be a problem if there are many transactions. With Firestore it is advisable to keep a balance field at the user level and update it with triggers whenever new transaction is added, modified or deleted.